# Java popup messages configuration

Tags: java

I'm using this code to get a popup message:

```
ti.displayMessage("Message name: " + message_name
                  , "Message text: " + message_text
                  , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
```

How do I add more lines to this popup message box? For example, the 1st row is `message_name`. Then the next row is `message_text`. But what if I want to add more lines? Something like this:

```
ti.displayMessage("Message name: " + message_name
                  , "Message text: " + message_text
                  , "Message type: " + message_type
                  , "Message from: " + message_from
                  , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is `ti.displayMessage()` from a library, or did you write it yourself? What kind of object is `ti`?

Comment: its a trayicon, TrayiIcon ti; ti = new TrayIcon(imageIcon, "Prisijunges kaip - " + vardas_pavarde, pmSystemTray);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in the second parameter:

```
 "Message text: " + message_text + "\nSecond message: " + message_text2 + ... AND SO ON
```

Note the use of `\n` which begins a new line, as you wanted.

Comment: +1 . I deleted my answer. As it was same as your except `\n`.